# Object-Relational Mapping with Hibernate - What Does "Sessionbound" Mean?

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm currently trying to take my first steps with Hibernate, but unfortunately I don't really get what "sessionbound" means.

Let's say I've got a transient object. Once it's made persistent, it not only has an ID, but is also "sessionbound". But why is that worth mentioning?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A Session in Hibernate is closely related to a transaction, and also serves as a first level cache. Every time you read or store an object, it is automatically bound to the current session (thus placed in the L1 cache).

Most importantly, as long as an object is bound to the session:

- You can take advantage of lazy loading of relationships (otherwise you will get the dreadful `LazyInitializationException`).
- All changes to this object from that moment will be automatically populated to the underlying database. As long as an object is bound to the session, there is no need to persist it manually.

Answer (score 1):

Also keep in mind that when using a transaction management layer like the one found in spring, your session will typically go away when your outermost transaction is comitted:

```
public class MyRep implements Rep {
   @Transactional
   public MyObject findMyObject(..) { ... }
}
```

So when you activate transaction management in spring, and lets assume you're not already in a transaction, if you do this:

```
MyObject o = rep.findMyObject(...);
```

By the time this method finishes, your object is no longer bound to a session (because spring has closed your session).  There's ways to overcome this, but i won't get into that here, just wanted you to be aware.